# CentOS new Tiger VNC version

Tags: centos

I have Tiger VNC Server 1.3.1 installed on my CentOS7 system.

Is there an easy and quick solution to install the newest version of TigerVNC Server?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use below command to install or update Tiger VNC Server package.

```
yum -y install tigervnc-server    # To install the Package

yum update tigervnc-server   # To Update the Package
```

Follow the below link for more guidance.

http://www.elinuxbook.com/tigervnc-server-configuration-remote-desktop-application-for-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Updating any packege in CentOS, if you use YUM for installation, for all packages is following:

> yum update

For a certain package

> yum update *package_name*

for check is there any available updates

> yum check-update